# Canvas fillText() not accepting variable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to have text drawn to a canvas, where the text is taken from an input element (or possibly other elements in the future).

I can't seem to get `fillText()` to accept a variable that has the value of the input field.

```
var getText = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
ctx.fillText("i" + getText,10,50);
```

Only `i` will show up, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: what does `console.log(getText);` print?

Comment: Need to see more of the code here. I'd like to see the inputText element and how it is defined. Or at least see the value of getText. Outputting to the console makes debugging and fixing these simple issues trivial.

Comment: My best guess is that getText is either empty or not of type string or int or float.
It's not undefined as if it was `i` wasn't shown.
So please provide the `console.log(getText);` as @le_m suggested

Comment: Might be value of input <input type="text" value = "name" placeholder = "name">. But for that he has to use event handler to get input of user and output on canvas as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

I had a variable declaration timing issue, getText was being applied on window load (and thus empty), not on button press (when it has a value).